# How to release the returned object in JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

A memory leak has occurred in my program.

Please help me find the location of the memory leak and tell me how to fix it, thank you.

#### Code

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_cn_test_encoder_JNIEncoder_encodeEncryptBuff(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject obj,
        jbyteArray ucInBuffer,
        jintArray unInbufferLen,
        jintArray unOutbufferLen) {

    jbyte *bytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(ucInBuffer, 0);;

    int chars_len = env->GetArrayLength(ucInBuffer);

    unsigned char* chars = (unsigned char *) malloc(chars_len);
    memset(chars,0,chars_len);
    memcpy(chars, bytes, chars_len);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(ucInBuffer, bytes, 0);

    int inLength = env->GetArrayLength(unInbufferLen);
    int* inArray = env->GetIntArrayElements(unInbufferLen,0);

    int outLength = env->GetArrayLength(unOutbufferLen);
    int* outArray = env->GetIntArrayElements(unOutbufferLen,0);

    unsigned char* encryptBuff = Encode_Encrypt_Buff(chars, (unsigned int*)inArray, (unsigned int*)outArray);

    jbyteArray bArray=env->NewByteArray(*outArray);

    env->SetByteArrayRegion(bArray, 0, *outArray, (jbyte *)encryptBuff);

    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(unInbufferLen, inArray, NULL);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(unOutbufferLen, outArray, NULL);
    free(chars);

    return bArray;  // java needs byte array
}
```

#### Memory usage

> [image: memory usage]

Comment: You don't have to release the returned object, so that isn't the problem here. You are leaking `encryptBuff`.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, you are right. I solved the problem with `delete encryptBuff`, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `delete encryptBuff`, and I don't need to release the returned object.

#### Code

```
...

free(chars);

delete encryptBuff;  // Add this line

return bArray;
```

#### New memory usage

> [image: new memory usage]